# Two way binding using Select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new to angular and I'm confused about needing to use `$scope.$watch` in the this very simple [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/LJNRtLtH4wurXIuRvo2p?p=info) in order to see my selection change.  If the `$watch` is removed, the alert is not triggered. Should `selection` not be automatically bound when I select something and then the change event should trigger a digest and automatic watch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need **$scope.$watch**. You can simpy use [**ngChanged**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChange) directive.

From Docs (emphasis mine)

> Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input. **The expression is evaluated immediately**, unlike the JavaScript onchange event which only triggers at the end of a change (usually, when the user leaves the form element or presses the return key). The expression is not evaluated when the value change is coming from the model.

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cZWCixgAb3YxUVc1VTEX?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for that.  My confusion arose because, for simple input elements that don't have change events, there's no need to bind an event handler to a function in the controller.

Comment: Correction, I can see what you're saying. For simple input elements the javascript onChange event is being propagated, whereas for select elements that's not the case and I need to explicitly use the ng-onChange directive.